# Casa Endeavor Ceiling Fan: Slight hum, and major wobble

Tags: ceiling-fan

New Fan.

I have installed at least 8 ceiling fans in the past.

Juan, the CSR of the seller  who I spoke with last week suggested several balancing options, nothing seems to be working.

Never had a significant issue such as these two with a fan:

## 1) A definitive hum in low speed;  is this normal for the Casa Endeavor (it is in the bedroom and it is quite annoying, at night)?

2)  The fan just will not seem to balance. I have installed several fans and balanced with no serious issues afterward.

So far, with me checking all the screws, and trying about 100 different balancing combinations.  Still wobbling on high speed, and low speed.

I am exhausted.

Though, after researching and reading, I  discovered one blade (out of 5 blades) is off by 1/4 inch meaning all other blades are 13" off the ceiling, and one blade is 12.75 inches off the ceiling.

## Could 1/4 inch make the difference with balancing?

Thoughts?

Comment: Balance is when the center of mass is on the axis of rotation- looking straight up that axis i.e. from below. The blades being up or down slightly won't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

I did a wb search for Casa Endeavor as I had never heard of this brand.
I found lots of info many with links to user manuals and installation instructions for Casa Endeavor

At least it does't appear to cheap fan.  I saw one priced @ over $300.

Is this a new installation.  Has it always had these problems ?

If I was there I would first remove the blades and all the screws that are used to attach them.
Did each blade have the same number of screws (usually 3 per blade) ? None are missing ?
Now with the blades removed does the fan still hum ?
Does the fan shaft still wobble.?
If the answers to either of these qustions is yes the something is wrong with the motor.

When you turn off the power to the fan does it coast or stop instantly.
(With no blades it will probably not coast as long but if it stops instantly there is something machanically wrong. Bad bearing(s) or something misaligned.)
With power off and the blades removed can the blade mount be turned easily by hand ?
No  ?  Motor has a problem.
There must be a blade balance problem.  Some fans have weights attached to make the weight of all the blades equal. Maybe one came off ?

If without blades mounted there is little or no hum and no wobble of the shaft then blade balance must be the problem.
Devise a means of comparing the weight(s) of the blades a pair at a time.

Do the blades all match.  Not one from another model of fan ?